# FindMinimum finds a zero value for solving a system but does not converges. Can I interpret it as the solution for system?

Tags: numerics

I am solving a system of three non-linear equations for three unknowns. I am using `FindMinimum` to minimize the norm of residuals of the system. I have played a lot with the starting points and the working precision. Finally, I have found values for the unknowns such that the norm of residuals of the system is zero but it gives me an error that the system failed to converge. My question is that whether I can interpret the values as the solution of the system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite likely, you may do so, but it is hard to say without further knowledge about the problem at hand. The norm of the residual is a rather objective condition for a solution - unless the system you want to solve is not severely ill-conditioned.

The error message suggests that `FindMinimum` is not satisfied with the accuracy of the result. You can try to lower the value of the option `AccuracyGoal` or increase the value of the option `MaxIterations` and see wether the message disappears.

I am not sure; usually `FindMinimum` uses only the norm of the gradient of the objective to determine convergence. This is however method dependent.
If your system is underdetermined and if `FindMinumum` also uses the distances between the iterates as convergence condition, it may be the case that the iterates generated by `FindMinimum` meander along the solution manifold.